# 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL' R

Tags: r

**Data Frame**

This is the aggData data frame.

```
 week   month   clean$TimeElapsed
1   7   2   233.3788428
2   8   2   197.321859
3   9   2   262.9656766
4   9   3   228.9536539
5   10  3   231.9331015
6   11  3   297.7748849
7   12  3   276.6380882
8   13  3   291.0149907
9   13  4   255.198273
10  14  4   344.8059474
11  15  4   278.0266588
12  16  4   285.8060417
13  17  4   319.1550685
14  18  5   266.6978501
15  19  5   257.9400897
16  20  5   230.6477697
17  21  5   214.5926981
18  22  5   215.9222798
19  22  6   209.9551517
20  23  6   252.4327421
21  24  6   271.0315055
```

**Code**

I am using the TTR library, importing

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
install.packages("TTR")
install.packages("plotrix")

library(TTR)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotrix)

#import the data
## Create a directory to store the data
dirName <- "data"
dirPath <- "D/Developer Productivity"
dir <- file.path(dirPath, dirName)
dir.create(path = dir, showWarnings = TRUE, recursive = FALSE)

#read in the data
fileName <- "avgdata.csv"
file <- file.path(dir, fileName)
data <- read.csv(file)
clean <- data[c(1, 9)]

#add some date columns
clean$newDate <- strptime(as.character(clean$Date), "%m/%d/%Y")
clean$month <- strftime(clean$newDate, "%m")
clean$year <- strftime(clean$newDate, "%Y")
clean$week <- strftime(clean$newDate, "%U")

#aggregate data based on weekly averages
aggData <- aggregate(clean$TimeElapsed ~ week + month, clean, FUN = mean) 

#calculate the moving average
ema.20 <- SMA(aggData$TimeElapsed, 20) 
ema.2 <-SMA(aggData1$TimeElapsed, 2)

#create graph
barp(aggData$TimeElapsed, col = "grey70")
lines(ema.2)
points(ema.2)
```

**Problem**

the ema lines are throwing the following error:

```
Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
```

From all of my googling, it is acting like my data frame has null value in it

My end goal is to graph a moving average line on top of a bar chart of the data in the aggData data frame.

Comment: You should use `aggregate(TimeElapsed ~ week + month, clean, FUN = mean)` and not `aggregate(clean$TimeElapsed ~ week + month, clean, FUN = mean)`

Comment: @lmo Why do I need to specify the data frame in some instances, and not others? e.g. clean$TimeElapsed or just TimeElapsed

Comment: Some functions, such as `aggregate`, `lm`, `glm`, and `reshape` have a data argument where you provide the name of the data.frame (sometimes a matrix will work). If the data argument is provided a data.frame, then it is not necessary to provide df$ in front of the variables. It is also possible to avoid using df$ when you use the `with` and `within` functions.